# Shifting amplitude from one basis to another with a control qubit

Tags: quantum-gate, no-cloning-theorem

I was reading a [forum](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9928657) where people were talking about a proposed quantum algorithm that solves an NP-complete problem in polynomial time. The algorithm appears to have flaws (after all, none of you have probably heard about it). One comment went like this:

> However, there is a rather simple proof that shows that the maximum amount of amplitude which you can transfer from one component of a quantum state to another using a control qubit is fundamentally limited by the Unitarian nature of quantum operations.

I don't understand this comment. The writer does cite the no-cloning theorem without any mention of it. Is that citation referring to this claim? If so, i've never heard the no-cloning theorem stated this way. In any case, I want to investigate the claim.

I've devised a scenario where a control qubit (4d qudit or 2 qubits, it doesn't matter) acts on an equal superposition of two qubits.

[image]

Where the gate $G$ is

$$
\def\a{\color{#FF33BB}{\frac{1}{2}}}
\def\b{\color{#1C3C93}{\frac{1}{6}}}
\def\c{\color{#37D717}{-\frac{5}{6}}}
$$

$ G = \begin{bmatrix}
\a &\a &\a &\a &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 \\
\a &\c &\b &\b &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 \\
\a &\b &\c &\b &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 \\
\a &\b &\b &\c &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 \\
0 &0 &0 &0 &\c &\a &\b &\b &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 \\
0 &0 &0 &0 &\a &\a &\a &\a &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 \\
0 &0 &0 &0 &\b &\a &\c &\b &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 \\
0 &0 &0 &0 &\b &\a &\b &\c &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 \\
0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &\c &\b &\a &\b &0 &0 &0 &0 \\
0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &\b &\c &\a &\b &0 &0 &0 &0 \\
0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &\a &\a &\a &\a &0 &0 &0 &0 \\
0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &\b &\b &\a &\c &0 &0 &0 &0 \\
0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &\c &\b &\b &\a \\
0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &\b &\c &\b &\a \\
0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &\b &\b &\c &\a \\
0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &\a &\a &\a &\a
\end{bmatrix}$

Now, assuming some other part of the circuit sets the control qudit to a given setting, $|setting\rangle = |0\rangle, |1\rangle, |2\rangle $ or $ |3\rangle$, applying the gate $G$ should have the following effect

$$
G \Bigg[ |setting\rangle_4 \otimes \frac{1}{2} \Big( |00\rangle + |01\rangle + |10\rangle + |11\rangle \Big) \Bigg] \rightarrow $$

$$
\begin{cases}
|setting\rangle \otimes |00\rangle, & |setting\rangle = 0 \\
|setting\rangle \otimes |01\rangle, & |setting\rangle = 1 \\
|setting\rangle \otimes |10\rangle, & |setting\rangle = 2 \\
|setting\rangle \otimes |11\rangle, & |setting\rangle = 3 \\
\end{cases}
$$

Essentially, $G$ would have the effect of sending all the amplitude to the state corresponding to $|setting\rangle$, which is precisely what the claim above places limits on due to the unitarity of quantum mechanical operators. It's easy to check that $G$ is unitary, so what is the maximum amount of amplitude transfer?

Comment: I guess the comment is related to the proof of optimality of Grover's search. It's worth having a look at that proof to see what they're trying to do. It at least helps to start to understand what they mean by amplitude transfer (although I don't feel confident enough about trying to express it exactly....)